# Runtime error 424 Compile error, Object Required - VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I need a simple bit of VBA code to work, however I keep getting runtime error 424.

I have looked over many other posts but found nothing that could help me

All I want to do is Vlookup with the id "individual" and find it in the ApplySublimits Worksheet.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim individual As String
    Dim individualCap As Single
    Dim subRange As Range

    Set subRange = ApplySublimits.Range("B:D")
    individual = "D02065"

    Range("C10").Value = individual

    individualCap = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(individual, subRange, 2, False)
End Sub
```

I keep getting this error but i dont understand why. Im very new to excel and would appreciate some help or guidance.

Comment: Which line you are getting this error??

Comment: What's `ApplySublimits`? You will have to give us enough information to reproduce the problem, else we can't help. See this for guidance: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: IndividualCap cant be a single it should just be a string.

Comment: I'm returning a Single to it from the "ApplySublimits" spreadsheet. That's why it's a Single.

Answer (score 0):

How can a single (a floating point number) hold something starting with D. It's not 0-9. If it's hex the &hD02065 is the way to do it. Plus numbers aren't enclosed in quotes.

Comment: While you point out a valid error it doesn't answer the question as asked. The OP is asking about a runtime error 424 whereas the error you've pointed out would be Error 13, Type Mismatch. Perhaps this would have been better as a comment?

Comment: 'individual' is a String. I didn't say anywhere it was a Single. Not constructive, -1 if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Declare and set `applysublimits` as the worksheet

Change `individualCap` to String

e.g.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim individual As String
    Dim individualCap As String
    Dim subRange As Range
    Dim applysublimits As Worksheet

    Set applysublimits = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set subRange = applysublimits.Range("B:D")
    individual = "D02065"

    Range("C10").Value = individual

    individualCap = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(individual, subRange, 2, False)
End Sub
```